# How to make a node reference field that can also behave as a text field if no reference exists

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax, entities

I'm looking for a flexibly way to allow a user to input a a field, but also to have that field be a node node reference if the the node reference already exists. In other words, lets say I have a content type called dog, each dog has a node reference for favorite toy, if the toy exists, this field should be a node reference, otherwise the user should be allowed to fill it in. 
     Conceptually I can think of two way to do this. One way, is just to make it a field, and then somehow link to another node if it exists. The other is to make it a node reference, and perhaps somehow auto - create the node when the user fills it in.

Recommendations? (using drupal 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of node references you could use term references and then use the [Autocomplete Deluxe](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module to have the user select existing terms or add new terms.

Actually, they there is support for references with [Autocomplete Deluxe for References](http://drupal.org/project/acdx_references).

Comment: 1: Term references wouldn't autocomplete from a list of users, and 2: Autocomplete Deluxe for References still doesn't allow you to enter text if the user doesn't exist, like the question requested.